# z3 python change logic gate children

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py, sat

My algorithm needs to modify the `children()` of the existing logic gate. Suppose i have the following code

```
a = Bool('a')
b = Bool('b')
c = Bool('c')
or_gate = Or(a, b)
```

I want to modify `or_gate` to be `Or(a, c)`.

I have tried the following:

```
or_gate.children()[1] = c
print(or_gate)
```

The above code doesn't work, `or_gate` is still `Or(a, b)`. So how do i change the children of a logic gate in z3?
Edit: i can't create new `Or()` that contains the children i want due to nested gate. For example consider the following

```
a = Bool('a')
b = Bool('b')
c = Bool('c')
d = Bool('d')
e = Bool('e')
or_gate_one = Or(a, b)
or_gate_two = Or(or_gate_one, c)
or_gate_three = Or(or_gate_two, d)
```

If we create new object instead of directly modifying the children of `or_gate_one`, then `or_gate_two` and `or_gate_three` should also be modified, which is horrible for large scale. I need to modify the children of `or_gate_one` directly.

Comment: Why would that be inefficient?

Comment: `or_gate.children()` probably returns a list that is independent of what `or_gate` stores internally. So changing that list isn't going to update `or_gate`. As for how to fix it, I'm not familiar with this z3 library. I suggest googling for the documentation to see if there's a method on the `Or` class that you can use to accomplish what you want.

Comment: On a side note: first create a solution that works before worrying about efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [substitute](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#ae8f9a59a4fcabbb12636c128178c5235) method:

```py
from z3 import *

a = Bool('a')
b = Bool('b')
c = Bool('c')

or_gate = Or(a, b)
print(or_gate)

or_gate_c = substitute(or_gate, *[(a, c)])
print(or_gate_c)
```

This prints:

```
Or(a, b)
Or(c, b)
```

I wouldn't worry about efficiency, unless you observe it to be a problem down the road: (1) z3 will "share" the internal AST when you use `substitute` as much as it can, and (2) in most z3 programming, run-time is dominated by solving the constraints, not building them.

If you find that building the constraints is very costly, then you should switch to the lower-level APIs (i.e., C/C++), instead of using Python so you can avoid the extra-level of interpretation in between. But again, only do this if you have run-time evidence that building is the bottleneck, not the solving. (Because in the common case of the latter, switching to C/C++ isn't going to save you much anyhow.)

Comment: Ah, i think i forgot to mention about nested gate in my question (or gate that uses another or gate as input), i will modify my question asap. Your answer work but it creates new object instead of modifying the existing one, which means i had to change the object reference to the new one for every single gate that uses the output of the old gate as input.

Comment: You cannot do such "destructive" updates on internal Z3 AST nodes. (Z3 maintains a bunch of invariants and internal bookkeeping, so making updates like this would lead to problems; in particular with garbage collection.) `substitute` is the only way to do this safely, and you'll have to apply it to all the expressions that need to change. (Since it'll create brand new ones.)

Comment: If you want mutability, I'd recommend *not* using z3's AST builders: Instead, design your own circuit type, which allows such modifications as you see fit. Once that DAG is built and finalized, then translate it to z3 in one go. That'd be the safe and most efficient way to implement what you're trying to do.

Comment: ooo... so there wasn't any way to modify the children of a formula in Z3?, okay thank you. I guess the only option left is to create class that takes Z3 formula as input, build it own internal modifiable structure, and output Z3 formula when it done. That would double the memory requirement, dang it....

Comment: it still doesn't make sense to me that the state-of-the-art theorem prover does not allow something as simple as modifying the children of a logic gate...

Comment: Not from the z3py API. If you use the lower level C/C++ API and link directly against z3, you can probably implement this; but keep in mind you'll have to traverse "all" the expressions and have them updated. See https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/ast/substitution/substitution.cpp for why this isn't an easy task, and it's much better to do such destructive updates outside of z3 and translate the final result.

Comment: okay thank you for the information. i will accept your answer.